# Missing internal table border between header and first row of data when setting cell background colour

Tags: itext7

When displaying a table I am getting a missing cell border line between the header row and the first row of data.  This occurs when the data cell is setting its background colour and would appear to be that setting the background colour is overwriting the top border of the cell.

Conditions for this to occur:

1. Table generated with default borders.
2. Table must have a header row.
3. First data row must be setting the background colour. Setting or not setting the header cell background colour makes no difference.
4. While this appears to happen most of the time, there are certain positions on the page where the border line appears (see screen shot).
5. On table that are split onto multiple pages (with repeated header row) the border is missing after each header.
6. Using iText7 version 7.2.5.0 on Windows 11 with Visual Studio 2022.
7. No use of column span or row span.

[image: Screen snapshot of output from sample program showing missing headers.]

The problem is reproduced easily.  The program below (console application built using .NET framework 4.7.2 in C#) I have tried different border widths and it appears that the problem is that the first data row is overwriting the cell's top boarder when adding the background colour.  Further with a wider border only part of the border is overwritten.  My analysis would suggest that the first data row cell has its top edge set 0.5pt too high.  Then in the case of the default border it is completely overwritten, for wider boarders it overwrite part of the border.

Various examples are reproduced in this program, the screen shot is the first page of the document this creates.

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Layout.Borders;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iText.Layout.Renderer;
using iText.Layout.Layout;

namespace iTextTableTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static private Cell[] GenerateCells(Table table, Int32 rows, Int32 columns, Boolean hasHeader)
        {
            Cell[] cellList = new Cell[rows * columns];
            for (Int32 iRow = 0; iRow < rows; iRow++)
            {
                for (Int32 iCol = 0; iCol < columns; iCol++)
                {
                    Cell cell = new Cell();

                    if ((hasHeader) &&
                        (iRow == 0))
                    {
                        cell.Add(new Paragraph(String.Format("Header Col{1}", iRow + 1, iCol + 1)));
                        table.AddHeaderCell(cell);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.Add(new Paragraph(String.Format("Cell R{0}, Col{1}", iRow + 1, iCol + 1)));
                        table.AddCell(cell);
                    }

                    cellList[(iRow * columns) + iCol] = cell;
                }
            }

            return cellList;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Creating a PdfWriter 
            String dest = "C:/Temp/iTextTableTest.pdf";
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
            // Creating a PdfDocument  
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
            // Creating a Document   
            Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

            // Creating a table with header row and no backgrounds
            float[] pointColumnWidths = { 150F, 150F, 150F };
            Table table = new Table(pointColumnWidths);

            GenerateCells(table, 4, 3, true);

            document.Add(new Paragraph("Table 1 - No background colors set."));
            document.Add(table);
            document.Add(new Paragraph());

            // Create a table with header row and cell backgrounds
            table = new Table(pointColumnWidths);
            Cell[] cells = GenerateCells(table, 4, 3, true);

            foreach(Cell cell in cells)
            {
                cell.SetBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(224, 255, 255));
            }

            document.Add(new Paragraph("Table 2 - Background color added to each cell.  Missing border between header row and first data row."));
            document.Add(table);
            document.Add(new Paragraph());

            // Create table with only top data row setting background
            table = new Table(pointColumnWidths);
            cells = GenerateCells(table, 4, 3, true);

            cells[1].SetBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(224, 255, 255));
            cells[3].SetBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(224, 255, 255));
            cells[5].SetBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(224, 255, 255));

            document.Add(new Paragraph("Table 3 - Background color added to selected cells.  Seems to depend on the position on the page as " +
                                       "to when the border line goes missing.  Here the same table is added twice.  First OK, second with " +
                                       "borders missing."));
            document.Add(table);
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Table 3a - Same table repeated.");
            para.SetMarginTop(6);
            document.Add(para);
            document.Add(table);
            document.Add(new Paragraph());

            // Create a table without header row and cell backgrounds
            table = new Table(pointColumnWidths);
            cells = GenerateCells(table, 4, 3, false);

            foreach (Cell cell in cells)
            {
                cell.SetBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(224, 255, 255));
            }

            document.Add(new Paragraph("Table 4 - No header row, all borders present."));
            document.Add(table);
            document.Add(new Paragraph());
            document.Add(new AreaBreak());

            // Create a longer table without header row and cell backgrounds
            table = new Table(pointColumnWidths);
            cells = GenerateCells(table, 40, 3, true);

            foreach (Cell cell in cells)
            {
                cell.SetBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(224, 255, 255));
            }

            document.Add(new Paragraph("Table 4 - Header row with rollover to next page.  The border may be preset on the first " +
                                       "header but always missing border on each subsequent page after the header row. " +
                                       "This appears to depend on where on the page the table starts."));
            document.Add(table);
            document.Add(new Paragraph());

            // Create a longer table with header row and cell backgrounds also define the borders
            table = new Table(pointColumnWidths);
            cells = GenerateCells(table, 50, 3, true);

            Border border = new SolidBorder(1.5f);
            border.SetColor(ColorConstants.BLUE);

            foreach (Cell cell in cells)
            {
                cell.SetBorder(border);
                cell.SetBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(224, 255, 255));
            }

            document.Add(new Paragraph("Table 5 - With header row and defined borders."));
            document.Add(table);
            document.Add(new Paragraph());

            document.Close();
        }
    }
}
```